# Passing Facet class to Chart.facet method

Tags: python, altair

I'm trying to create a function to create a chart where you can pass Row, Column, or Facet classes as arguments to the chart. Here is a very simplified version:

```
def make_chart(data, x, y, **kwargs):
   return alt.Chart(data).mark_line().encode(x=x, y=y).facet(**kwargs)
```

If I pass **row = alt.Facet('z')** or **column = alt.Facet('z')** as the kwargs the function works, but if I try to pass **facet=alt.Facet('z', columns=2)** then I get an error becasuse the facet method doesn't accept the Facet class as an input, instead expects **field='z', columns=2**.

So I tried to unpack the arguments of **alt.Facet('z', columns=2)** using it's to_dict() method, but I get an "Z encoding field is specified without a type" error.

I know I can access the individual properties of alt.Facet using alt.Facet('z', columns=2)[property], but is there any way to get all the properties as a dictionary? or that I can pass alt.Facet as an argument?

I need to create some layered faceted charts, so I cannot use facet inside the encode.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altair does not currently allow for `.facet(facet=alt.Facet('col', columns=1))`, but you can use `.facet(facet=alt.Facet('col'), columns=1))` instead:

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd


def make_chart(data, x, y, **kwargs):
   return alt.Chart(data).mark_point().encode(x=x, y=y).facet(**kwargs)

make_chart(
    pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2], 'y': ['b', 'a']}),
    'x',
    'y',
    facet=alt.Facet('y'),
    columns=1
)
```

[image]

Comment: I read altair documentation and it has columns as a parameter of alt.Facet. Am I interpreting this wrong? https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/channels/altair.Facet.html

I generally use  alt.Chart().mark_line().encode(x=x, y=y, facet=alt.Facet('z', columns=2)), so I thought I could pass it along with the alt.Facet

Comment: @Samesand I usually use the `columns` param directly in `.facet` myself, because the other way doesn't work, but you are correct that it is documented that `alt.Facet` has a `columns` parameter and that [`.facet` should accept `alt.Facet` or a string](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/blob/ea35b6157f627f56c6e5075611908eeb7b929dba/altair/vegalite/v4/api.py#L1858-L1860). I don't know if the intended usage is for this to allow for `.facet(facet=alt.Facet('col', columns=1))` as you are attempting, but you can raise an issue on GitHub while using the other way I suggested in the meantime.